# Why would ghosts leave behind slime?

Tags: ghostbusters

In Ghostbusters, the ghosts leave behind slime ("ectoplasm").  Why would ethereal beings leave behind slime?  What's the in-universe explanation of this?

Comment: Out of universe - sort of - [wikipedia has an article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectoplasm_(paranormal)#Phenomenon) about why ghosts leave behind ectoplasm.  Although it doesn't sound like the same type of stuff in the movie.

Comment: An in-universe explanation for "ghosts are made of ectoplasm, which sounds like it should be slimy"? Sorry, no.

Answer (score 5):

Per [Tobin's Spirit Guide](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Tobin%27s_Spirit_Guide):

> **[Ectoplasm](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Ectoplasm#Ectoplasm)**: A thick, viscous substance, ectoplasm is formed when ghosts interact with the physical world. Usually seen as a viscous, mucuslike slime, ectoplasm has also been encountered in mistlike and even crystalline forms.
>
> **[Ectoplasm Residue](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Ectoplasm#Ectoplasmic_Residue)**: identifies areas of paranormal contact or interaction. While some ectoplasm can be seen with the naked eye, Ectoplasmic Residue can only be seen while using the P.K.E.-enhanced Paragoggles.

Both are from [Ghostbusters: The Video Game (realistic version)](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Ghostbusters:_The_Video_Game_(Realistic_Versions)), the last I heard, this version is considered canon by Dan Akroyd

From the Ghostbuster's wiki page for [Ectoplasm](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Ectoplasm):

Comment: If Dan Akroyd says it it must be true!

Comment: Hey, it works for George Lucas!